# High GLMER dispersion parameters

Tags: r, glm

I am running a glmer with a random effect for count data (x) and two categorical variables (y and z):

```
    fullmodel<-glmer(x~y*z + (1|Replicate), family = poisson, data = Data)
```

However, when I look at the dispersion parameter:

```
    > dispersion_glmer(fullmodel)
[1] 2.338742
```

It is way higher than 1. Does this mean my model is over dispersed? How do I correct it. I want to keep my random effect but when I tried to swap the family to quasipoisson it says you can't use it for a glmer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This sounds more like a stats question; the good folks over at Cross Validated should be able to help.

Comment: Thank you! I've put it on there !